# How to convert char to int in R retaining leading zeroes

Tags: r

I am converting a column that has characters such as 000024, 000120 etc to integers.

My code is as below

```
 df$colname <- as.integer(df$colname)
```

But this removes the leading zeroes and I see result as 24, 120. Is there any way I can prevent it?

Comment: what do you need this for ?

Comment: I just imported data from excel. I have a column that's a primary key with a list of IDs which have leading zeroes. Let's call it Product_Num. I was trying to convert the field from char to int, but I'm not really sure if that is required

Comment: if it's an id you don't need to connect to another table, you don't need to touch it. You can also convert it directly at the importation step, but it seems to me you came here without an issue :)

Answer (score 3):

Integers don't have a fixed number of leading zeros (or I guess you could say they have infinitely many leading zeros) so computers don't track those if the values as numeric. It's only when displaying them, or turning them into a string that you add a certain number of zeros.  When you need them to be pretty, you can add zeros with functions like `sprintf("%06d", c(12, 120))` but those return strings in the end (and they assume all values will use the same number of digits).